# Link prediction with input data

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a list of files, an I use the KNN algorithm to classify these files.

```
dataset = pd.read_csv(file)
training_samples = get_sample_number(dataset)
X_train = dataset.iloc[:training_samples, 5:9]
y_train = dataset.iloc[:training_samples, 9]
X_test = dataset.iloc[training_samples:, 5:9]

# Feature Scaling
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.fit_transform(X_test)

# Fitting classifier to the training set
classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5, metric='minkowski', p=2)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

Now I have my categories in my y_pred array. But I want to save the result in the file where I read the dataset. How can I link a prediction to the right row in the file (or dataset)?

Comment: Nitpicking comment: when scaling your test data, you should use `sc.transform` not `sc.fit_transform`. In other words, you should standardize the test data with the mean/std from the training data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First as "timleathart" mentioned, you need to fix your code by changing this line :

```
X_test = sc.fit_transform(X_test)
```

to:

```
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
```

For your question :

- you have already the number of samples (training_samples) used for training. so all you need is to iterate over the y_pred and save the values in new column in the dataset starting from "training_samples" as row index.

Comment: Iterating on pandas objects is generally a bad idea, especially when a simple vectorized alternative exists (as is the case here). In addition to being unidiomatic, it's often way slower than the alternative.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost: I would *strongly* advise against modifying your original data file. It introduces risk that your workflow will become unrepeatable.

To persist your results, I recommend doing something like this:

```
in_fname = '{}.csv'.format(filename)
out_fname = '{}_SCORED.csv'.format(filename)
dataset = pd.read_csv(in_fname)

... do stuff

dataset.loc[training_samples:, 'scores'] = y_pred
dataset.to_csv(out_fname, header=True, index=False)
```

If you really want to overwrite your original data, just set `in_fname=out_fname`. But I'd advise against it.